# Color Strip horizontal on Top with Image.plot in R

Tags: r, image

I am trying to put a color strip legend in the top of my plot using image.plot. The command horizontal=T in image.plot put it horizontally all right but on the bottom.
Thanks
Henri

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: I am not sure how to give a reproductible example. I would like to know if there is a way to put a color  strip legend, horizontaly on top of a graphic generated by image.plot. The option horizontal=T (in image.plot) put it on the bottom.